# error in npm install && npm run dev when installing breeze

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm, breeze

Im new to Laravel and wanted to use breeze authentication in my Laravel app.
I created my project and migrate my database tables then based on breeze tutorial I run

`composer require laravel/breeze --dev`

and

`php artisan breeze:install`

successfully. but I got these errors after running this code

`npm install && npm run dev`

and now its the result. can anyone help me?

```
F:\kishcharkh>npm install && npm run dev

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7(node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Invalid protocol: 127.0.0.1:

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2
(node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Invalid protocol: 127.0.0.1:
> @ dev F:\kishcharkh

> npm run development

> @ development F:\kishcharkh
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

        Additional dependencies must be installed. This will only take a moment.

        Running: npm install vue-template-compiler --save-dev --production=false

npm ERR! Invalid protocol: 127.0.0.1:

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\masih\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-12T09_52_45_253Z-debug.log
F:\kishcharkh\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:93
                                throw err;
                                ^

Error: Command failed: npm install vue-template-compiler --save-dev --production=false
npm ERR! Invalid protocol: 127.0.0.1:

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\masih\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-12T09_52_45_253Z-debug.log

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\masih\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-12T09_52_45_353Z-debug.log

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

and here is the package.json file:

```
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
        "alpinejs": "^2.7.3",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.2.1",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65682669/edit) your question to include your `package.json` file? The log looks like there may be some garbage in the file.

Comment: Maybe `127.0.0.1:port` for a url that needs to be prefixed by `http://`

Comment: Do you have a proxy set up? Does `npm config get proxy` and `npm config get https-proxy` return `null`?

Comment: yes , both returned null. @cbr

Comment: Try deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install --verbose`. Does it reveal anything new?

Answer (score 0):

I did fight with that one day ago. I discoverd that if the error persist after of:

> rm -rf node_modules
> rm package.lock.json
> npm cache  clear --force
> npm install
> npm run dev

Then the error was that my node was outdated.  Update to lastest version

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do with your node version. You can resolve this situation by removing the node_modules folder and then try installing it again after updating the version to the latest.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34950028)